# Strange behaviour of AccessController.checkPermission

Tags: java, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to learn about Java's permission model. I tried this sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File file = new File("/etc/passwd");
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));) {
    reader.lines().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  FilePermission perm = new FilePermission("/etc/passwd", "read");
  AccessController.checkPermission(perm); // throws Exception
}
```

This prints the contents of `/etc/passwd` fine, but throws an exception in the end:

`Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "" "read")`

Why is it that the file read works fine, but a check for the permission gives a negative result?

Answer (score 1):

Likely because the JVM doesn't have a SecurityManager configured.  Without a SecurityManager configured there will be no AccessController call made.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc6.html#a19349

Comment: Ah, yes. Adding `-Djava.security.manager` to VM arguments throws an exception when accessing the file. But I don't understand why AccessController fails when no security manager is installed. That is, why isn't AccessController not reporting the real permissions?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the AccessController is reporting the correct permissions.  It's just that due to history there are two layers of security enforcement in Java.  Without a security manager in place none of the JDK code will talk to the AccessController (so the configured security policy means very little).  This is done so that people who still subclass SecurityManager to enforce a custom security policy don't have their security bypassed.

As to why the permission is denied, I'm guessing you must have either installed a custom Policy instance or you've tweaked the policy settings file.

Comment: I haven't installed a custom Policy nor tweaked any policy settings file. I am running the posted code on an unmodified JDK 8u5. Is that a bug then?

Comment: Ugh - sorry misread the default java.policy file on my machine.  Only java extensions get "AllPermission" by default.  Other domains get a pretty limited set: go look at the lib/security/java.policy file in your JRE home.  It's normal and expected that you see that exception.

Comment: I understand the issues better now. But from a programmer's perspective this still seems unexpected. Shouldn't AccessController.checkPermission() be permissive when no SecurityManager is installed? Probably it has performance penalties? otherwise I can't imagine why it couldn't check whether SecurityManager is installed or not.

Comment: There are two layers of security policy enforcement, the SecurityManager and the AccessController.  They are independent, and called in that order.  It doesn't make a whole lot of sense in hindsight - but that's what happens when you have the twin constraints of backwards compatibility and security enforcement going on.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing strange here, this is exactly the behavior specified in the javadoc. The `checkPermission` method **will** throw [if the permission is not granted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#checkPermission%28java.security.Permission%29):

> Throws: AccessControlException - if the specified permission is not permitted, based on the current security policy.

while the constructor for `FilePermission` will **not** throw if the specified permission is not granted, but [only when the input is invalid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html#FilePermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - If actions is null, empty or contains an action other than the specified possible actions.

Comment: I wasn't expecting constructor for `FilePermission` to throw an exception. Rather, expected the constructor of `FileReader` to throw a permission denied exception, in accordance with the exception from `checkPermission`. I mean, why is `checkPermission` failing but I am still able to read the file?

Comment: Ops I didn't realize that. That's strange, I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: try calling `getActions()` on the permission object. Also try a different file in a completely different folder. There might be something path/file specific going on here.