# File check permission

Tags: java, java-7

I'm trying to check permission of the given file using the following code snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        FilePermission fp = new FilePermission("E:/test.txt", "read");
        AccessController.checkPermission(fp);
        System.out.println("Ok to open socket");
    } catch (AccessControlException ace) {
        System.out.println(ace);
    }
```

So when I run it, it gives me following exception:

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:/test.txt" "read")`

All the rights are enable on file but it throws me access denied exception.

Comment: Maybe open file regularly and use file.canRead() ?

Comment: What JVM security policy is in place?

Comment: Can you try with `E:\test.text`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of AccessController.checkPermission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476145/strange-behaviour-of-accesscontroller-checkpermission)

Answer (score 5):

Use the following snippet to check if you can read the file:

```
boolean canRead = new java.io.File("E:/test.txt").canRead();
```

`File.canRead` checks if the SecurityManager (if there is any) allows to read the file **and** if you have read rights in the file system.

Using `AccessController.checkPermission(fp)` will only not throw an exception if there is a security context which **implies** the permission. This is not the case when you simply start a Java app as in your example.